# Calling activity from a widget

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I wan't to create an activity, that will send SMS using an smsmanager, and then, I wan't to call this activity on widget button click, so that sms is sent. Is this posible ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start an activity from a widget, just use remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent on some view and use PendingIntent.getActvitiy to create a PendingIntent that launches the activity.